# Split on '||' in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, series

**I m trying to split on ||**

```
ser=pd.Series(['there a guy || I will have a bite || no can do','I can do || more'])
ser.str.split('||')
```

**I should get output as [['there a guy','I will have a bite','no can do'],['I can do','more']]
but I m getting this

```
0    [, t, h, e, r, e, s,  , a,  , g, u, y,  , |, |...
1    [, I,  , c, a, n,  , d, o,  , |, |,  , m, o, r...
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Double `||` is processing like regex, so need escape this values by `\`:

```
a = ser.str.split('\|\|')
print (a)
0    [there a guy ,  I will have a bite ,  no can do]
1                                  [I can do ,  more]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple columns:

```
>>> ser.str.split('\|\|',expand=True)
              0                     1           2
0  there a guy    I will have a bite    no can do
1     I can do                   more        None
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid escaping, I would suggest using character classes instead:

```
ser.str.split(r'[|]{2}')

0    [there a guy ,  I will have a bite ,  no can do]
1                                  [I can do ,  more]
dtype: object
```

Alternatively, there's no need to escape yourself because `re.escape` can do it for you.

```
import re
ser.str.split(re.escape('||'))

0    [there a guy ,  I will have a bite ,  no can do]
1                                  [I can do ,  more]
```